# Plasma 5 - Wallpaper background reset to blur at every login

Tags: kde, plasma5

I upgraded to Kubuntu 18.04 LTS recently. Every time I boot the computer and log in, the background setting of the wallpaper (Right click on the desktop > Configure Desktop) appears to be reset to "Blur", even though "Solid color" is selected. See screenshot:

[image: The background of the wallpaper is blurred even if "Solid color" is selected]

Every time, I need to select "Blur" and then reselect "Solid color" to ungrey the Apply button, which yields the expected result when clicked:

[image: The background of the wallpaper is now as it should be]

Is there any way to make the change permanent? I'm running Plasma 5.12.7, KDE Frameworks 5.44.0, and Qt 5.9.5. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like it might be a bug?